# LM358 Output Voltage Issue / Compensation

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, single-supply-op-amp

I am working on a PCB to take a 0-5 VDC signal and convert into a 1-5 V signal with two channels and two op-amps. This is done with a voltage divider that takes the 5 V signal and converts to 0.995 V, where it is then buffered by U2B and U3B. The 0-5 V control signal is divided down to 0-3.96 V. U2A and U3A are taking a 0-3.96 V signal, and are acting as a voltage follower (buffer). The outputs of U3A and U3B are added together to get a 1-5 V output, and the outputs of U2A and U2B are also added together.

The issue arises when the control signal input is at 0 V, I am getting an output offset voltage of ~100 mV. As I understand, the LM358 is not RRIO (rail-to-rail input-output), which is where I am having issues.

I have 2 possible solutions that I can think of at this moment:

1. Add a charge pump to take the +5 VDC supply power, and convert it to -5 VDC to be used on the op amp's V- pin.
2. Substitute the LM358 for an RRIO op-amp. (I am not sure which one to use)

How can I fix this?

[image]

(Please ignore R1 & R2 it was my poor attempt at pull-down resistors.)

Comment: Most people here would suggest switching out the LM358 for something more modern even if you were using dual rails and swapping in a rail to rail opamp is probably easier than designing in a -5V rail if you don't need voltage swing below ground. Specific product recommendations are off topic here etc etc, but just searching for one on all the big electronic parts distributors (Digikey, Mouser, Arrow, etc) will show you hundreds if not thousands. Then it comes down your application - you'll want something that's "unity gain stable".

Comment: Are "offset" voltage important?

Answer (score 2):

The circuit is way too complicated for what you're trying to do.
A slight refactoring eliminates the rail-to-rail problem altogether.

First of all, a single opamp can do the conversion you're looking for:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9jnLy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The opamp inputs range between 5/9 V and 25/9 V, or 0.555 V to 2.778 V.

And to generate the 1 V output bias, you need just one copy of this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6VKy9m.png)</sup>

And again, the opamp inputs sit at 1.000 V.

Comment: Fantastic! I knew that I was over complicating things, but I lack the experience to do so. Thank you for the great suggestions.